# Dynamically show/hide a label based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKsjr/20/

I would like to know how to add a label field to the bottom of that text field that prints invalid or valid depending on the user input, how could I implement this idea?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="fname" maxlength="255" size="8" value="First Name" required/>
```

JS:

```
function isfname(text) {
    var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
    return reg.test(text); }

$(".fname").keyup(function (e) {
    var $test = $(this);
    if (isfname($test.val())) {
        $test.css("background-color", "rgb(140, 202, 165)");
        $test.css("color", "white");
    } else {
        $test.css("background-color", "rgb(198, 95, 88)");
        $test.css("color", "white");
    }
}).blur(function (e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
    $(this).css("color", "#4A4F4B");
    if (!isfname($(this).val()))
        $(this).val('First Name');
}).focus(function (e) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
    $(this).css("text-transform", "capitalize");
    if (!isfname($(this).val()))
        $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried adding: `var elem2 = document.createElement('label');
   elem2.innerHTML = "valid";    
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elem2);` but it's useless because it simply puts the label where I don't want it and doesn't change if it's valid or invalid, it can also print the result multiple times which isn't good, for example, it can say valid valid valid.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery's validation plugin?

Comment: Yes I have but I would like to take this approach.

Comment: Add one `label` right after your text input and hide it. If form is invalid - show and hide again as new validation started.

Comment: that's genius can you try to share your solution as a fiddle so I can properly select you as the person who helped me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Put input in, lets say div

   ```
   <div>
      <input type="text"  class="fname" maxlength="255" size="8" " value="First Name" required/>
   </div>
   ```
2. Update your javascript

   ```
   $(".fname").keyup(function (e) {
   var $test = $(this);
   $test.parent().find('div').remove();//remove error element before validation
   if (isfname($test.val())) {
       $test.css("background-color", "rgb(140, 202, 165)");
       $test.css("color", "white");

   } else {
       $test.css("background-color", "rgb(198, 95, 88)");

       $test.css("color", "white");
       $test.parent().append('<div>Invalid name !</div>');//create error element
   }
   }).blur(function (e) {
   $(this).css("background-color", "");
   $(this).css("color", "#4A4F4B");

   if (!isfname($(this).val()))
       $(this).val('First Name');
   }).focus(function (e) {
   $(this).css("background-color", "");
   $(this).css("text-transform", "capitalize");

   if (!isfname($(this).val()))

       $(this).val('');

   });
   ```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKsjr/24/ It doesn't seem to be working, you do understand that I am trying to add a label to the text-field, for example if the background goes green it uses the label valid but if it's red it uses invalid.

Comment: Thanks, I've got a solution don't worry.

Comment: Used div to display below the input. You have to change style of lable to display at the desired position: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKsjr/28/

Answer (score 0):

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKsjr/25/)

First, we can use some semantic HTML to describe our elements better.

```
<input type="text" id="fname" maxlength="255" size="8" 
       placeholder="First Name" required />
<label for="fname">First name is required</label>
```

Then we can define a Validator function, which aids us in validating.

```
function Validate(expression){
    return (function(){
        var $el = $(this),
            $label = $("label[for='"+$el.attr('id')+"']"),
            val = $el.val();

        if (expression.test(val)) {
            $label.fadeOut();
        }
        else {
            $label.fadeIn();   
        }
    });
};
```

Creating validators in this way is flexible.  Here's a simple "one word" check for our first name.

```
validate = {
    first: Validate(/[a-z]+/i)
};
```

Our binding to the HTML is then much simpler.

```
$('#fname').blur(validate.first).keyup(validate.first);
```

Comment: What you've given me doesn't seem to be working check your fiddle rakerainbrigand.

Comment: Sorry, fiddle updated.  By the way, any specific styles you want can (and should) be set with CSS.

Comment: Almost but no cigar your fiddle is fu*ked, u_mulder had a good solution, I am going to say you answered the question because of your effort, thanks bud.

Comment: What's not correct in the fiddle?  I don't like leaving incorrect answers, especially if they're accepted.

Comment: I hope you don't mind sharing your success with Uttam K C, you've both helped me equally and it's really hard for me to pick a solution so I decided that he should have it because he is new.